# How do I make a automatic label changer?

Tags: timer, label, basic

So my Question is that how do I make it so a label in visual basic change every 5 seconds but I want it to loop?

My Version of visual basic is - Visual Studio 2013

Thanks - Zacimac

Comment: Set the timer at 1000 millisecond, every 5 ticks of the timer, re update your label.

Comment: I don't know how, And I want it to change text every 5 seconds

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
startVal=1
endVal = 5
For var = startVal To endVal
  lblLabel.Text = "Text " + var 
  await Task.Delay(2000)//Await five second
  lblLabel.Refresh()
next var
```

Comment: But I want the text to change every 5 seconds with a different sentence or label

Comment: Use the timer control. Set a time interval and you can change the text as you want.

Comment: But i want the TEXT to change every 5 seconds for example - "Text 1" Then after 5 seconds text says "Text 2" than after 5 seconds "Text 3" Then it loops! Get what i'm saying?

Comment: what text you want to change ? give me example ? is it some random words etc ?

Comment: Where do I put my text?